# Returning the number of records and ignoring duplicates in MySQL / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, analytics

I have a mySQL table with records of users who have visited my site. What I want to do is find out how many records there are in my table, but only counting duplicate values once in order to find out how many unique visitors there are.

I'm using the following code to find how many hits I'm getting each month.

```
$pageViews = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM JB_Statistics WHERE month='$month' ");
$numRowsPV = mysql_num_rows($pageViews) ;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pageViews)) {
    $month = $row['month'];
}

echo "<p>Month: $month, Total Hits: $numRowsPV </p>";
```

The table JB_Statistics also has an **ip address** and **browser field** with **unique information for each hit**, so is there a way of using this to modify the code above and find the **unique visitors per month**?

Apologies if this is straight forward but every search I carry out returns topics about only finding duplicate records.

Comment: Remember the rule: **Do ALL the data calculations in the database**. This is what databases were invented for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)                             AS DistinctClicks
     , COUNT(DISTINCT IpAddress)            AS DistinctIpAddresses
     , COUNT(DISTINCT Browser)              AS DistinctBrowsers
     , COUNT(DISTINCT IpAddress, Browser)   AS DistinctUsers      --- hopefully
FROM JB_Statistics
WHERE month='$month'
```

Comment: technically wrong, you need to check for both IP & Browser, as you could have people eliminated from the count behind a NAT'd IP

Comment: @Jakub And how would adding browser help? What if it's an entire company using IE and they all show up as the same IP?

Comment: @antisanity, usually a browser has distinct fingerprints, your argument is moot, as my suggestion simply adds another distinction per question details.  Grouping by IP does not provide a full picture.

Comment: @Jakub Neither does grouping by IP and Browser. As you said, it's just another distinction... but it certainly doesn't make ypercube _technically wrong_ or you anymore _right_.

Comment: @Jakub: Technically, not even `COUNT(DISTINCT IpAddress, Browser, MacAddress, AgeOfUser)` provides correct count. Not if I have a twin brother that uses my pc occasionally.

Comment: @ypercube, case in point, poster doesn't track mac, age of user, or shoe size... they said they **track ip + browser**.  My point was that your answer just didn't go far enough to distinguish as you used one of the two. I'm simply pointing this out.

Comment: @Jakub: You are right in that point. I missed the `browser` in the first reading. It's the OP's responsibility to choose the identifying columns that work in his case.

Answer (score 2):

Not accurately based on your description.

The above answers are correct in terms of SQL, you could use a **GROUP BY** or **DISTINCT** clause but IP address does not give you unique visitors. There can be any number of users behind a single IP.

You may have to rethink what you're using to identify what's unique about each record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$pageViews = mysql_query( "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uniquefield) FROM JB_Statistics WHERE month='$month'" );
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $pageViews );
echo "<p>Month: $month, Total Hits: ", $row[0], "</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query in the following way:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ipfield) FROM JB_Statistics WHERE month='$month'"
```

That should produce what you want.

Answer (score 0):

use GROUP BY: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM JB_Statistics WHERE month='$month' GROUP BY ip_address`